# Can I use a flutter package in android kotlin/java?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, kotlin, flutter-dependencies

I would really like to use a flutter package in my kotlin/java android app. Is that possible?

Thank you!

Comment: it is not possible

Comment: No, it is not possible! 
But you can find an alternative library for android kotlin/java as well.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible! But you can find an alternative library for the same thing